# How to handle Observable, Promise, and concrete return types in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making an Angular 12 app and I'd like a general handler to populate my tables with data from different types of sources. Sources being either `Observable<T[]>`, `Promise<T[]>`, or just plain `T[]`.

A generic base directive calls an abstract method that each derived component has to implement. Take the following example that loads data via `Promise`:

```
@Directive()
public abstract class BaseListDirective<T> implements OnInit {
    
    items: T[];
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.load();
    }
    
    load(): void {
        this.listItems.then(result: T[] => { this.items = result; });
    }
    
    abstract listItems(): Promise<T[]>
}

@Component()
public class ImplementingComponent extends BaseListDirective<Customer[]> {
    
    constructor(public service: CustomerService){}
    
    listItems(): Promise<Customer[]> {
        return this.service.getAllItems();
    }
}
```

What I'd like to change is allow `listItems()` to take different data sources such as `loadItems(): Promise<T[]> | Observable<T[]> | T[]`.

How is this usually done? Via type checks and branching statements? Such as:

```
load(): void {
    const source = this.listItems();
    if (source instanceof T[]) {
        // we got concrete type, nothing fancy to do
        this.items = source;
    } else if (isObservable(source)) { // via rxjs
        // got Observable
        source.subscribe((result: T[]) => { this.items = result; });
    } else {
        // definitely a Promise
        source.then((result: T[]) => { this.items = result; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you own the BaseListDirective code or are you trying to extend this base directive without changing anything besides the override. If you own the base implementation why not just have @Input() items: NgIterable<T> and avoid all these type checks? 

If you have to have multiple types your type check branching is what I’ve seen done before, although I think it looks messy.

Comment: I own it, yes. I'm filling AG Grid with data this way, and usually it's just a one-off HTTP request, so a Promise would be enough. However, I'd like to allow the use of static data, or some Observable that goes through some modification. I'd rather not build a new Promise, or call .toPromise() on observables just for that.

Comment: I think what you’re doing with type checks is what is most commonly done. The only thing is might change is do an if promise type check and change the else to a throw error.